# How do you count all possible variants of combinations?

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations

I know that when you need to count all possible variants of combinations of 3 numbers from 0 to 9 and the numbers can be repeated you can use this: 10^3. But what if numbers can't be repeated (you can't make a combination like 116, 787 etc.)? What if the numbers place doesnt matter (116 and 161 and 611 is the same combination)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For combinations of `m` elements from a set of size `n`, we can distinguish four possibilities, depending on whether or not elements can appear more than once, and whether or not the order of the selected elements is important.

If elements can be reused, we sometimes say that the combination is "with replacement" because the selected element is replaced -- not removed -- from the original set.

The four formulas: (I write the binomial coefficient n choose m as `n C m`)

- Ordered with replacement: `nm`
- Ordered without replacement: `n!/(n-m)!`
- Unordered with replacement: `(n+m-1) C m = (n+m-1)!/(n-1)!m!`
- Unordered without replacement: `n C m = n!/(n-m)!m!`

(In fact, there are other similar problems, so this is just four of the [Twelvefold Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way).)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [binomial coefficient](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html) or [number of k-combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations) or `n choose k` formula. For example, to choose 3 elements from a set of 10:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10+choose+3

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers can't be repeated, there are 10*9*8 possible outcomes. Or 10! (10 factorial) outcomes. Think of it in terms of picking a number out of 10. Now you only have 9 to pick from. Then 8.. etc.

If the order does not matter and numbers do not repeat, it is a combination problem written like 10C3 in the notation nCr where n=10 and r=3
Link: https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php?n=10&r=3&action=solve